# Search inside JSON column of postgres (array)

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonpath

hi i have json fields with values
["dawdaw@gmail.com", "dawdaw@gmail.com"]

why this sql return nothing ?

SELECT *
FROM client
WHERE emails ->> '$.[*]' like '%gma%';

try different and check expresion in https://jsonpath.com

Comment: Have a look at `jsonpath` functions and expressions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH). `select * from client where emails @? '$[*] ? (@ like_regex "gma")';`